# No manual entry for git

Tags: osx, environment-variables, path, man

I'm able to use `man git` when `MANPATH` is set to the following:

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:
```

However, when it doesn't include the trailing colon, man says it can't find the entry:

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnuman:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman

$ man git
No manual entry for git
```

The manpage is located at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man/man1/git.1`, and I'm running the command from my home directory. I understand the trailing colon tells man to search the current directory as well as `MANPATH`, so why does it cause man to find the entry under `/Library`?

Comment: Outside and inside git, what happens if you type `env | grep MANPATH`.  It's possible that your outside manpath isn't exported and so not really being used.   The git.1 manpage is in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man/man1/git.1` on 10.11.5 which wouldn't be found with that MANPATH

Comment: @StephenHarris what do you mean inside git?

Comment: I meant "insude tmux" which is how the earlier version of your question read, and which you understood correctly in the previous incarnation.   You appear to have totally rewritten the question and deleted your own comments...

Comment: @StephenHarris right, sorry I realized the problem has nothing to do with tmux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You should not have to manually set `MANPATH` on a Mac.

Unlike most Unix-based systems, OS X automatically selects an appropriate search path for man pages based on the contents of `PATH`.  The rules for this are described in the section "Search Path for Manual Pages" in `manpath(1)`.

The configuration file for this has been in other locations in the past, but currently resides in `/private/etc/man.conf`.  This file is read by `manpath(1)`, which generates a suitable search path.  However, this behavior is disabled if `MANPATH` is manually set in the shell.

## Addressing the trailing `:`

Although I cannot find confirmation of this in the manpage, it appears that if `MANPATH` is set in the environment with a `:` at either end, the environment's `MANPATH` is added to the output of `manpath`.

Examples:

```
$ MANPATH='.:' manpath
/Users/me/.:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man

$ MANPATH='':.' manpath
/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/Users/me/.
```

Comment: Unsetting `MANPATH` solved some problems, e.g. now I can use `man git` inside of tmux. However `man ls` displays the entry for BSD ls and not GNU ls which I installed through brew. I still don't understand the effect of the trailing `:`.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is before `/bin` in my `PATH`. I don't have `/usr/local/man/man1` but I do have `/usr/local/share/man/man1` and `/usr/share/man/man1`. It appears that brew puts mapages in the former but they are all prefixed with `g`. It also puts them in `/usr/local/opt` and advises you to add this to your `MANPATH` in your bashrc if you want e.g. `man ls` to work like you expect. Bleh.